# ArcGIS exporting files to Access 2007

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Does anyone know how to export a shapefile out of ArcGIS into an Access 2007 database?

Comment: Are you referring to an *.accdb vs a *.mdb?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the understanding on how you should go about.

http://wagda.lib.washington.edu/gishelp/tutorial/AccessImportShp.pdf

I know the text is not helpful but the images should help you through.

Basically, what the pdf is explaining, is that you can export the shapefile to a PersonalGeodatabase (which you will have to create before hand) and save it in a .mdb format. .mdb is a MSAccess recognizable format which is something that you can see when you open the particular file in MsAccess (As shown in the pdf in the link).

Personally, I would not recommend exporting the file to MSAccess or Personal Geodatabase. There are lot of [flaws related](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?topicname=types_of_geodatabases) to it. I would recommend that you export the data to FileGeodatabase.

Comment: Great - thanks for the information. If you recommend FileGeodatabase - I will look into that program for sure.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a file geodatabase if you want to connect to it via Access - it just doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The official way that ESRI suggest you create a link to an Access 2007 (accdb) database is discussed [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32976).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Table to Table" tool to convert a Shapefile .dbf into an MDB table.